# AG-Grid React Change colour of Cell Flash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I have a created a ag grid which flashes rows when they are updated, but I can see that the flash colour is blue by default. Is there a way of changing this colour?
Example of the flash shown here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/flashing-cells/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Each time the call value is changed, the grid adds the CSS class
> ag-cell-data-changed for 500ms by default, and then then CSS class
> ag-cell-data-changed-animation for 1,000ms by default. The grid
> provided themes use this to apply a background color.
>
> If you want to override the flash background color, this has to be
> done by overriding the relevant CSS class.

See documentation [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/flashing-cells/#how-flashing-works).